# How to generate a graph presenting all the possibilities using Python

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, graph, networkx

I need to write a python code that allows me to generate a tree of possibilities that depend on each other. In fact, if we have two vectors: `a=[0, 1]` and `b=[0, 1]`, we can construct 4 different possibilities:

- `(0, 0)`
- `(0, 1)`
- `(1, 0)`
- `(1, 1)`

If we will take `(0,0)` as the parent node, we can generate 3 edges from `(0, 0)` to all other possibilities: `(0, 0) -> (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1)`.

Then for each possibility we can generate 3 edges to the other possibilities, e.g:

- `(0, 1) -> (0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1)`
- `(1, 0) -> (0, 0), (1, 1), (0, 1)`
- `(1, 1) -> (0, 0), (1, 0), (0, 1)`

I need to repeat that N times. The result should be a tree, where every non-leaf node has 3 successors - for every possibility except the current.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour),
read up on [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). especially show some effort towards a solution.

Comment: Can you please ellaborate  on how (0,1) , (1,0) and (1,1) create the same three sets ?

Comment: In fact (0,1) will be seen as a parent in its tour and taking into consideration that the first variable can be either 0 or 1 and the same for the second variable, we can say that (0,1) is one combination of 4 possible values (0,0), (0,1),(1,0),(1,1) but we eliminate the case where it returns to itself so the case (0,1) will be omitted and so, we have 3 possible next cases ((0,0),(1,0),(1,1)).  Same for the others. Have you any idea how this can be achieved ????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct naming of your graph is [complete graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_graph). The good graph processing libraries for Python - `networkx` - has a special function to generate this type of graphs:
[complete_graph](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.generators.classic.complete_graph.html#networkx.generators.classic.complete_graph)

**Edit 1:** I constructed the workflow for you that solves your problem. You can copy-paste it into your Jupyter notebook, but note that you need:

- networkx
- graphviz
- pydot

to be installed.

```
import networkx as nx

# Set main parameters
items = {(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1)}
root = (0, 1)
N = 4

# Calculate the number of nodes for our tree
node_count = sum((len(items)-1)**i for i in range(N))

# Construct full r-rary tree
G = nx.full_rary_tree(len(items)-1, node_count, create_using=nx.DiGraph)

# Create LG-topologically sorted array of nodes
# NOTE THAT NODES' IDs AREN'T EQUAL TO YOUR ITEMS
lgts = list(nx.lexicographical_topological_sort(G))

# Get the first element to preset its label
first = lgts[0]

# Preset an empty label for all nodes
nx.set_node_attributes(G, '', 'label')

# Set the label for the root
G.nodes[first]['label'] = root

# For all nodes:
for node in lgts:
    # Get needed names
    s_labels = list(items - {G.nodes[node]['label']})
    # For all childs:
    for s_node in G.successors(node):
        # Set the child's label
        G.nodes[s_node]['label'] = s_labels.pop()

# Create dict for drawing labels
labels = {n: G.nodes[n]['label'] for n in G.nodes}

# And draw the final graph
nx.draw(
    G,
    pos=nx.nx_pydot.graphviz_layout(G, prog='dot'),
    with_labels=True,
    labels=labels
)
```

Finally you will get this graph:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it seems true, but I want that in each iteration, the system generates new nodes, even if they exist already in the graph. So from 00 -> 01, 10, 11 its ok but then for 01, I want new nodes presenting 10,11,00

Comment: I don't understand. Do you want to construct a tree of possible paths? Because if you want to create the node equal to the existiing in graph, they will merge.

Comment: Yes, I want a tree. Think of it as follows: I have 4 combinations (00,01,10,11), I start by 00 and link it to the other three nodes, then each time I take one of these nodes and link it to the other three nodes, maybe I should generate a new label each time, so that I ca have new nodes,  and I repeat that for N times !
I'm really stuck, any idea please

Comment: Updated an answer for you.

Comment: Thank you soo much , this is the result that I look for. Thank you again

Comment: If you are glad by my question, I will be appreciated if you will accept my answer.